# MockK: verify that a function is called with a parameter of specific subclass type of a parent class

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I am using MockK for testing. Language: Kotlin.
I have a `sealed class A` with a few subclasses, say `B`, `C`, and `D`, which is used as a parameter for a function call. I need to make sure that a function is called with one of the subtypes of `A`.
For that I tried to do this:
`verify { instance.doSomething(any<B>())}` and it passes. However, I tried to do `any<C>` and `any<D>` and it still passes.

How do I verify that the function was called with a parameter of type `B` and only `B`?

Comment: Leaves you to wonder why any() is generic when it doesn't check the type...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe `ofType(type)` is what you need.